# Prioritizing foundation/slab repair and sewage pipes?

Tags: plumbing, slab, sewer

My house is old, built around 1955. It has two outstanding issues,

- Slab repair (very likely needs to be done, doors don't line up and I see cracks above some sills, it has slab repair before)
- Sewage pipes are pre-PVC, I believe they're all galvanized and original.

Assuming both of these things must be done, which should be done first?

- If the house has sewage pipes replaced, and then afterward the foundation is repaired, I'm concerned that the house will sewage pipes first replaced and backfilled will potentially break when the house is adjusted and reset.
- If the house has its foundation repaired and then they dig under the foundation and backfill I'm concerned it may resettle and need another repair.

Is there an order these two things should fall in?

Comment: A slab and a foundation are two very different things. The former is (usually) just flooring. Please revise to clarify which we're discussing. Tell us about your footings, foundation walls, and floor slab. Photos would be dandy. Also tell us what kind of repairs you're anticipating. "Adjusted and reset" isn't something a person normally does with a 1950s house foundation.

Comment: ↑ are we taking a bit of patch-up or a full underpin?

Comment: Do you know whether the piping was buried under the slab, or it was cast with the concrete floor? Why do you feel there is a need to replace the piping?

Comment: @r13 don't know the answer (cast in slab or under the slab). But the response there is because all of my neighbors have replaced it, and I believe this is original. I also found a disturbing amount of [Green Gobbler products](https://greengobbler.com/) in the garage, so I have reason to believe that I should expect difficulties in the future. ;)

Comment: @isherwood I think it's called "Slab-on-grade foundation" I'm not sure how to refine the question please feel free to suggest an edit. I believe the terms are used interchangeably in Houston. But that could be a regionalism, or I could just be wrong.

Comment: No, you're right. A slab _can_ be a foundation if it has integrated footings. We need to know all that, though. Please put it in your question.

Comment: Since your neighbors have already done that, why don't you ask them to offer some advice, which will be very beneficial.

Comment: @isherwood I don't know it has integrated footings.. I haven't seen them. I just know it's a house on top of a concrete "slab" that we also call a foundation. I'm not actually sure how they did it in the 1950s. What should I look for?

Comment: Well, that's somewhat critical to good answers. A slab can be knocked out with no ill effects. A "thickened edge" slab foundation is probably more sensitive to modification.

Comment: @r13 I did, they said we would need to replace the sewage pipes eventually, and that our foundation (and all of them in this neighborhood) need periodic repair and that we should save for it.

Comment: Your building is sitting over a thick layer of expansive clay, which is quite common in the Huston area, and is very difficult to deal with. I don't know to what extent your slab has been damaged, but if the piping is under the slab, then I suggest you shall take this opportunity to consult with a structural engineer to get the most economical and durable solution to avoid bigger headaches down the road.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-PVC sewage drains were cast iron which is different from galvanized steel. Our neighborhood of slab-on-grade houses in Dallas TX was built 1969-70 at the time when builders were changing from cast iron drains to the newer plastic drain pipe of two plastics--PVC and ABS.  Our builder, Fox & Jacobs, used ABS plastic drains on our house, but most of the 270  houses in our tract development and surrounding tracts have cast iron drains.

I know of a number of houses where the cast iron drains have been replaced, but most are still functioning. If your house was built with best quality cast iron drains, your drains might not need to be replaced at this time. From what I see all replacement is with PVC. The particular type of PVC required in the City of Dallas is called Schedule 40, which is stronger than the base grade PVC. I believe the base grade is called DWV for drain, waste, vent.

I have also seen a number of houses which have had foundation repair. Most repair is done by placing piers under the perimeter "beam" of the slab, but sometimes piers are placed in the interior. If you think you need both drains replaced and foundation repair, consult with plumbing contractors first and ask them which they recommend doing first. The process of driving the piers can damage drains (and water supply pipes) so I would think the foundation repair should be done first, but consult with the contractors. The contracts I have seen with foundation repair contractors state explicitly that they are NOT responsible for any damage to drains or water supply pipes.

Comment: I do have areas in the house where the slab was clearly already repaired by drilling 3x3 holes through the floor. I'm unsure of how long ago that repair was. But it wasn't done under the last home owners. And the cracks above some of my sills are newer than the coat of paint, which was done by the previous home owners.

Comment: Is that 3 ft x 3ft or 3 inches x 3 inches? Such holes might be for access to repair leaking drains or water pipes. Full replacement of drains (at least in Dallas) requires tunneling under the slab starting from the outside edge.

Comment: How large is the house and where in Houston is it located? Specialized foundation engineers have equipment which will reveal where your house slab is out of level and by how much. Do you have any indication that your drains are leaking?